# How to Export Client Certificate from Firefox for Android on non-rooted device

Tags: firefox-for-android, certificates

I had a website install a client certificate into my Firefox browser (v35.0.1) on my tablet and I want to export and backup the certificate. I've found out after the fact that Firefox on android doesn't actually provide any native mechanisms for managing the certificate store (and does not integrate with the Android native certificate store). Additionally, all Firefox add-ons I've found are out of date, preventing them from being installed.

I found an article here that suggests copying the cert9.db and key4.db files to PC and using a third-party application to extract the certificate and key, however this device is not rooted and the file browsers I've tried do not allow browsing the true root filesystem. As a workaround, I tried putting the path to the files in Firefox to download them to somewhere more accessible, however Firefox refuses to download them (though of note: it does *see* the files.

Is there any other way to access the certificate store in Firefox for Android or retrieve the cert/key db files from which I can extract the certificate?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox's sync facility? I'm not certain if it does sync certificates - worth investigating though. If it does work, you sync with a desktop version and manage/backup certificates from there.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, as I don't have access to my desktop right now (though will in a while). I also don't know if the Firefox sync will include the cert db, but I'm somewhat doubtful that it will. I'll have access to my desktop in a couple of hours and will try there when I can.

Comment: @garethTheRed - sorry, didn't tag you in my reply.

Comment: I still received it though.  This [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/client-certificate-manager/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) installed on my Android Firefox - may be worth a try. I can't confirm whether it worked or not as it simply told me that I had no certificates installed (which is true!).

Comment: I sync'd between a desktop (which has a cert) and a mobile (which doesn't have a cert) and Firefox sync doesn't seem to copy certificates - ah well, it was just a thought...

Comment: @garethTheRed This plugin allows me to view the detailed of and delete certificates, but doesn't let me actually export them unfortunately. And Firefox sync does not include the browser certificate store, though does seem to be wanted according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583935

Comment: Does [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/786035?s=certificate&as=s) help?

Comment: @garethTheRed As I said, this device is non-rooted (it's actually brand new!) and I have no way to actually get the files. Firefox itself can see thr m, but refuses to download, and no other applications I've found will let me get them. I'm reluctant to resort to USB debug push/pull, but if I get desperate enough I'll certainly try it.

Comment: The article doesn't imply that it needs to be rooted, although if you're struggling to access the files then it may indeed need to be. My phone is rooted, therefore I can't  categorically state that you can access them without being rooted unfortunately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an Android question, not a Linux question, since it's really about software on the tablet and not about software on your PC. I flagged for migration to [android.se] (do not repost).